# Nginx 502 Bad Gateway DotNet App

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, dotnet-framework, 502

I am using NopCommerce 4.60.5 , with Ubuntu 23 , Nginx as Reverse proxy to upstream .net app.
Site is up and running with some minor issues that im working on. however, issue starts when I have restart nopCommerce from admin when some changes to the setting happens and i get 502 Bad Gateway error.
nginx error log shows , connection refused to upstream server. I have local server and production server , both have same exact issue.
is been 7 days that i have search and tried almost everything out there to see i can fix this but nothing has worked. here is my configuration ..

```
server {

# include snippets/snakeoil.conf;



# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name www.MYDOMAIN.ca MYDOMAIN.ca;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;



proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'upgrade-insecure-requests';
proxy_http_version    1.1;
proxy_set_header      Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header      Connection keep-alive;
proxy_set_header      Host $host;
```

#proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_cache_bypass    $http_upgrade;
#proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
#proxy_set_header      X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
#proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Host $host;
#proxy_read_timeout    900;
}

```
listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
```

server_name MYDOMAIN.ca www.MYDOMAIN.ca;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/supplysolution.ca/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/supplysolution.ca/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
if ($host = [www.MYDOMAIN.ca](http://www.MYDOMAIN.ca)) {
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

```
if ($host = MYDOMAIN.ca) {
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name MYDOMAIN.ca www.MYDOMAIN.ca;
return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

}
I would really appreciate if anyone can help me in fixing this issue that been having for past 7 days .

Comment: I am not familiar with this software but based on you configuration looks like should be a service running on the port 5000, is it the server service running? Could you try login into the server and run curl localhost:5000 if you dont get any response that mean the service that start the app on port 5000 is not running.

Comment: Hi. upstream server is running on port 5000. this is how Dotnet server works. site in general working fine , both front end and back end. is restarting nopcommerce cause the 502 error. normally there is 10 second wait before upstream server starts . i guess there must be someway configure nginx to wait 10 seconds before reconnecting to upstream server .